# Vue: How to reference environment variables in a markdown file?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, environment-variables, markdown, gridsome

I've been looking for a way to access an environment variable in a markdown file. Example if writing *foo.md*:

```
Bacon ipsum dolor amet turkey ham drumstick, [landjaeger]({{ process.env.GRIDSOME_URL }}/landjaeger)
```

and also within an `<iframe>`:

```
<iframe height="{{ process.env.GRIDSOME_HEIGHT }}"
```

In my *.env* file I am able to reference the environment variable without any issues throughout the other files:

*.env*:

```
GRIDSOME_URL=https://path/to/somethinng
GRIDSOME_HEIGHT=450
```

but when I research documentation for my installed [Gridsome plugins](https://gridsome.org/plugins/):

```
"@gridsome/plugin-google-analytics": "^0.1.0",
"@gridsome/plugin-sitemap": "^0.2.1",
"@gridsome/remark-prismjs": "0.0.6",
"@gridsome/source-filesystem": "^0.6.0",
"@gridsome/transformer-remark": "^0.3.4",
"graphql-playground-html": "^1.6.22",
```

nothing in the documentation or their supporting repos demonstrates how to pass a global to a markdown file. When I research the site and other site's I'm not finding any results for Vue but I did find something for Hugo: "[Use Environment Variable in Markdown Files](https://ruddra.com/hugo-use-env-variable-in-md/)" which doesn't work in Gridsome.

#### Attempt:

*foo.vue:*

```
<template>
  <Layout>
    <h1>{{ $page.doc.title }}</h1>
    <div class="markdown" v-html="$page.doc.content" :height="height" />
  </Layout>
</template>

<page-query>
query Doc ($path: String!) {
  doc: doc (path: $path) {
    title
    path
    date (format: "MMMM D, YYYY")
    timeToRead
    content
  }
}
</page-query>

<script>
import { LinkIcon } from 'vue-feather-icons'

export default {
  components: {
    LinkIcon
  },
  data() {
    return {
      height: process.env.GRIDSOME_HEIGHT
    }
  },
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: this.$page.doc.title,
      meta: [
        {
          key: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: this.$page.doc.description
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

*foo.md:*

```
<iframe :height="{{ $height }}"
```

In Gridsome/Vuex how can an environment variable be passed down to a Markdown file and used?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know gridsome, but for the code you've posted, it could be solved in a pure Vue way. First you would have to make that env object available in frontend. E.g.:

```js
Vue.use({
  install (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$env = process.env
  }
})
```

When Vue builds/serves the project, it will get the env and make it available. Then you can use inside any component:

```js
...
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.$env)
  },
  data() {
    return {
      height: this.$env.GRIDSOME_HEIGHT
    }
  },
...
```

I'm sure there's lots of other ways of doing it.